# Many to many relation table name for tables with similar name

Tags: sql

I have two tables named `business` and `business_category` that have many-to-many relation. What name should I use for a third table that bind them together? I don't like `business_business_category` name at all.

Comment: I would have three tables, `businesses`, `categories`, `businessCatgories`.  But this is really a matter of opinion, which is why I'm voting to close.

Comment: I have another `*_category` tables. So I can't call table just a `categories`

Answer (score 0):

You could name it - **BusinessCategoryLink** or **BusinessesPerCategory**

Comment: Thank you. But I try to find a convention that contains both table names. Like a `business_to_business_categories`. Is there a common approach?

Comment: then maybe - BusinessesPerBusinessCategory

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you. Can make three table. `Business`, `categories`, `businesses_x_categories`. All business are will be in business table , all categories will be categories table and both table link will be `business_x_categories`.

Multible. Business have same categories. So we can link with same category and different business.